# C# Survey Quiz Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I am trying to make a multiple choice quiz and need the value of the input fields that I have below:

```
<input class="QuizButton" type="radio" name="Q1" value="1" onclick="ShowHide('Question3', 'Question4'), Q3log(1);" > [Question Text....]
```

How can I make this fully clickable instead of just a radio button? I have tried using  tags instead but this did not allow me to do a

```
Request.Form["Q1"]
```

request when trying to run my results function.

Comment: do you want to use radio buttons at all? Or just have a clickable element?

Comment: Just a clickable element, radio buttons seem to be the only ones that let me retreive their values but i am likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "fully clickable". If what you means is "How do I make the form element respond when either the radio button or it's text are clicked" you can use a `<label>` to do this.

```
<input type="radio" id="option1" />
<label for="option1">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" />
<label for="option1">Option 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" />
<label for="option1">Option 2</label>
```

Note the `for` attribute. It contains the `id` of the `input` that you want to associate it with. Specifying `for` causes both elements to behave as a single element for the purposes of UI interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input into label tags, that way the whole text + radio button will be clickable.

```
            <label>
            <input class="QuizButton" type="radio" name="Q1" value="1" onclick="ShowHide('Question3', 'Question4'), Q3log(1);">
             [Question Text....]
            </label>
```